# How to use JSLink (CSR) for multiple views of same list in Same Page?

Tags: view, jslink, client-side-rendering

I have a page with 2 views of same list. When I use the JSLink to render one of the column (request_id) which is present in both the views, in one view JSLink is working fine, but on the second view it is not working.  Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    // Initialize the variable that stores the objects.

    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {}; 
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Request_ID': {'View':ChangeStatusIcon}
    };

    // Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function ChangeStatusIcon(ctx)
{

    var AdminNo= ctx.CurrentItem.Admin_No;
    var Auto = ctx.CurrentItem.Auto_x0023_;
    var RequestDate= ctx.CurrentItem.Request_date;  
    var year = RequestDate.split("-");
    var Current_Year = year[2];
    var urltext="CLM_"+Current_Year+"_"+Auto;
    var url= "/sites/SCL/Lists/Admin%202/Item/editifs.aspx?&ID="+AdminNo+"";
    var coltxt="<a href="+url+" target='_self'>"+urltext+"</a>";
    return coltxt;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure that second webpart also has jslink file in the misc section when you edit the wp.

Comment: Can you see any javascript error in the console? Also, remove the script tags and paste your code in the js file and use that js file as JSLink in the webpart settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add condition to limit the view based on `ctx` properties(`ctx.view` or others).

Similar thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b18b8c4-ab34-4970-9696-7133928ced05/jslink-issues-with-multiple-list-views?forum=sharepointdevelopment).